# POST via $.ajax (with PhoneGap 2.6 and Zepto.js) on Android Woes

Tags: ajax, django, post, cordova, zepto

I am currently working on a PhoneGap app which is required to POST to a server (running Django). Unfortunately, we are not receiving the anticipated response when we perform this action: We get a 200 message with no data, rather than a 401 (unauthorized) with a json object.

Our javascript code is similar to: [this code](http://pastebin.com/FR5vGMVe)

The server-side python looks a bit like: [this code](http://pastebin.com/gZ99s5yE)

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: `login(request, form.get_user())` Did you call authenticate somewhere in that form? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not help you with your specific problem, but I can tell you that you will never get a 401 code back.
PhoneGap applications have an issue with it: they return code '0' instead of '401' for some reason.  It is on their official JIRA:

[PhoneGap JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2962?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13648218#comment-13648218)

So whatever you find for solution for your issue, you will just get a new problem.